# Redirecting to next page using jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i am developing web application using jsf with primefaces, i've used one login action and 2 xhtml pages. When i logged in it calls the action class and it is not returning to the next xhtml page

Problem in redirecting the page i've used primefaces 3.2 version jar file and i've configured jsf with jstl in the project facets.

my login xhtml page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"> 

<h:head></h:head> 
<body> 
    <h:form styleClass="loginPanelStyle">
       <p:panel id="panel" header="Login">  

        <p:messages id="msgs"/>  

        <h:panelGrid columns="3">  
            <h:outputLabel for="firstname" value="UserName" />  
            <p:inputText id="firstname" value="#{home.username}" required="true" label="UserName">  
                <f:validateLength minimum="2" />  
            </p:inputText>  
            <p:message for="firstname" display="icon"/>  

            <h:outputLabel for="surname" value="Password" />  
            <p:inputText id="surname" value="#{home.password}" label="Password" required="true">  
                <f:validateLength minimum="2" />  
                <p:ajax update="msgSurname" event="keyup" />  
            </p:inputText>  
            <p:message for="surname" id="msgSurname" display="icon"/>  

        </h:panelGrid>  

        <p:commandButton id="btn" value="Login" update="panel" actionListener="#{home.validateUser}"/>
    </p:panel>  
    </h:form>
</body> 
</html>
```

My Action Class

```
package com.cation.action;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import logon.Users;

public class LoginAction {

    private String username;

    private String password;

    private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "Cation";

    private static EntityManagerFactory factory;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public String validateUser() throws Exception {
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
        // Read the existing entries and write to console
        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM Users u where u.Login='"+username+"'");
        List<Users> userList = q.getResultList();
        Users user = (Users) userList.get(0);

        if(user == null){
            return "error";
        }
        return "home_page";
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

My web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Cation</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/login.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    This parameter tells MyFaces if javascript code should be allowed in
    the rendered HTML output.
    If javascript is allowed, command_link anchors will have javascript code
    that submits the corresponding form.
    If javascript is not allowed, the state saving info and nested parameters
    will be added as url parameters.
    Default is 'true'</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    If true, rendered HTML code will be formatted, so that it is 'human-readable'
    i.e. additional line separators and whitespace will be written, that do not
    influence the HTML code.
    Default is 'true'</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    If true, a javascript function will be rendered that is able to restore the
    former vertical scroll on every request. Convenient feature if you have pages
    with long lists and you do not want the browser page to always jump to the top
    if you trigger a link or button action that stays on the same page.
    Default is 'false'
</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and my faces-config xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd"
    version="1.2">
     <navigation-rule>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>login</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>home</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.cation.action.LoginAction</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>      
    </managed-bean>
    <navigation-rule>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>home_page</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/pages/homePage.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
     <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>user</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.cation.action.UserAction</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>      
    </managed-bean>
    <navigation-rule>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>addUser</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/pages/addUser.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
    <navigation-rule>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>successUser</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/pages/success.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
</faces-config>
```

can any one help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

To use navigation with `p:commandButton`, you need to use the `action` attribute and not the `actionListener`.

Change your button like this :

```
<p:commandButton id="btn" value="Login" update="panel" action="#{home.validateUser}"/>
```

Everything else seems fine in your code.

More info :

- [JSF action vs actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3909382/354831)